# 3D Basemap Adding 3D bars

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Hi everyone I wanted to create one of the examples of Basemap in 3D in [here](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html#adding-3d-bars), which its for 3d bars on geographical maps and their sample code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import numpy as np

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-20,llcrnrlat=0,urcrnrlon=15,urcrnrlat=50,)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_axis_off()
ax.azim = 270
ax.dist = 7

polys = []
for polygon in map.landpolygons:
    polys.append(polygon.get_coords())


lc = PolyCollection(polys, edgecolor='black',
                    facecolor='#DDDDDD', closed=False)

ax.add_collection3d(lc)
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.35))

lons = np.array([-13.7, -10.8, -13.2, -96.8, -7.99, 7.5, -17.3, -3.7])
lats = np.array([9.6, 6.3, 8.5, 32.7, 12.5, 8.9, 14.7, 40.39])
cases = np.array([1971, 7069, 6073, 4, 6, 20, 1, 1])
deaths = np.array([1192, 2964, 1250, 1, 5, 8, 0, 0])
places = np.array(['Guinea', 'Liberia', 'Sierra Leone','United States', 'Mali', 'Nigeria', 'Senegal', 'Spain'])

x, y = map(lons, lats)

ax.bar3d(x, y, np.zeros(len(x)), 2, 2, deaths, color= 'r', alpha=0.8)

plt.show()
```

But after I run that code I get this error:

AttributeError: 'LineCollection' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: I have no problem running your code. You may need to provide more info about the errors, S/W version.

Comment: How can I provide more info about errors?